# Calling A Few Print Function At Once

Tags: php, function, printing

May I know that is it possible to combine the printing functions below so that it will only be called once. Because my listTableOfUser function will add a few lines of data when it is called and i only need the data to be added once while printing all the tables.Thank you.

```
if ($table == "all") {
    print listTableOfUser( "alert", $userNm, $CCR_Trans);
    print listTableOfUser( "problem", $userNm, $CCR_Trans);
    print listTableOfUser( "vitalsigns", $userNm, $CCR_Trans);
    print listTableOfUser( "result", $userNm, $CCR_Trans);
    print listTableOfUser( "medication", $userNm, $CCR_Trans);
    print listTableOfUser( "functional_status", $userNm, $CCR_Trans);
    print listTableOfUser( "procedureP", $userNm, $CCR_Trans);
    print listTableOfUser( "immunization", $userNm, $CCR_Trans);
    print listTableOfUser( "family_history", $userNm, $CCR_Trans);
    print listTableOfUser( "social_history", $userNm, $CCR_Trans);
    print listTableOfUser( "planofcare", $userNm, $CCR_Trans);
    print listTableOfUser( "actor", $userNm, $CCR_Trans);
    print listTableOfUser( "medical_equipment", $userNm, $CCR_Trans);
    print listTableOfUser( "healthcare_provider", $userNm, $CCR_Trans);
    print listTableOfUser( "payers", $userNm, $CCR_Trans);
    print listTableOfUser( "encounters", $userNm, $CCR_Trans);
    print listTableOfUser( "advancedirective", $userNm, $CCR_Trans);
}
else  { print listTableOfUser( $table, $userNm, $CCR_Trans);
```

Comment: It sounds like you want a loop.

Comment: Just define a variable $output = "" and add any output data to it like "$output .= listTableOfUser(...)". At the end you just call "print $output;"

Comment: @SLaks Creating a loop will caused the function to be called many times isn't it?

Comment: just pass 1st param as an array.. and loop inside your listTableOfUser function..

Answer (score 1):

```
$tables = ($table == "all") ? array( 
                               "alert",    
                               "problem",
                               "vitalsigns", 
                               "result", 
                               "medication", 
                               "functional_status",
                               "procedureP",
                               "immunization",
                               "family_history",
                               "social_history",
                               "planofcare",
                               "actor",
                               "medical_equipment",
                               "healthcare_provider",
                               "payers",
                               "encounters",
                               "advancedirective"
                             ) : array($table); // prepared an array

foreach ($tables as $t) {
  print listTableOfUser( $t, $userNm, $CCR_Trans );
}
```

Comment: My listTableOfUser function will add a few lines of data when it is called and i only need the data to be added once while printing all the tables.Is it possible to do so? Thank you

Comment: Directly it’s not possible. You can’t prevent _some part_ of function of being executed. But you always have an option either to provide your own function in place of `listTableOfUser` or collect everithing and then filter the output using `preg_replace`.